# syntax of Iteration in K-mean Clustering With MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

i have a problem with using the number of iteration in MATLAB.
i use this code but there is no change in the number of iteration:

**Edit**

this is my code...

```
            clc;clear;close all;diary temp;
            cluster_data=unifrnd(-3,+3,[100 2]);
            optns = statset('MaxIter',500);
            [idx,ctrs]=kmeans(cluster_data,3,'dist','city', ...   
                              'display','iter','replicate',100,'options',optns);
            figure
            plot(cluster_data(idx==1,1),cluster_data(idx==1,2),'r.','MarkerSize',14)
            hold on
            plot(cluster_data(idx==2,1),cluster_data(idx==2,2),'b.','MarkerSize',16)
            plot(cluster_data(idx==3,1),cluster_data(idx==3,2),'g.','MarkerSize',18)
            plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'kx',...
                      'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
            plot(ctrs(:,1),ctrs(:,2),'ko',...
                      'MarkerSize',12,'LineWidth',2)
            legend('Cluster 1','Cluster 2','Cluster 3','Centroids',...
           'Location','NW')

            fid=fopen('temp');
            dat=textscan(fid,'%s');
            fclose(fid);
            delete temp

            dat=dat{1};
            i1=find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(dat,'sum')));
            ie=find(~cellfun('isempty',strfind(dat,'iterations')));
            i1=i1(1)+1;
            Nd=str2num(dat{ie(1)-1});
            ie=Nd*4+i1-1;
            dat=reshape(str2num(strvcat(dat{i1:ie})),4,Nd)';

            iter = dat(:,1) % <-- iterations
            sm = dat(:,4)   % <-- sum
            figure
            plot(iter,sm)
```

the issue is the number of iteration... how can i really increase the number of iteration?
however i increase the 'Maxiter' but no change appear.

Comment: Can you please post the results of running the command which indicate the problem you see?

Comment: u can see my code in edit section.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal working example](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates your problem in your question, please? That way, people can easily copy/paste it and ideally help you.

Comment: What kind of data is `P`? It's being read from a file. Can you provide a meaningful example?

Comment: The post have been updated. please check it.

Comment: The code works. You can change the iterations as I outlined in my answer. With the example you provided, the code needs about `14` iterations to converge. Set `MaxIter` to `5` to see that it doesn't converge any more because it has used an insufficient number of iterations. If your data gives you another error, provide an example of your data.

Comment: could u run my code with my reall data...? i uplaoded in mediafire. [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/view/znvrovb2gqatqgp/DataNano1.txt)

Comment: @AliTahoori Again, as I already said [in this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215422/syntax-of-iteration-in-k-mean-clustering-with-matlab#comment26744716_18215422), it works. I ran it with your data, and it needs only ~14 iterations to converge. So why do you want to increase the max number of iterations to 500? What is it you are not satisfied with?

Comment: ok, with 14 iteration, the code plot a diagram(iteration vs. CostFunction), can u see 14 point in the x-axes.??? i can see only 6 point...

Comment: however i change the MaxIter to 14, but there is 6 iteration only.!

Comment: because i coundnt post any question, i have to ask my question here... im sorry for that.

Comment: after solving the previous problem i would be really gratefull if u can describe Silhouette Function in brief... thank a million!

Comment: Let's take a step back. 1.) Your initial question asked about how you could change the number of iterations. I think this has been answered. 2.) You have issues with your plot. This should be a) a new question or b) a comment to your other question. 3.) You have a question about a silhouette function; that should be a new question. 4.) Why can't you ask questions? If that's truly the case, it's due to the quality of your existing questions. In that case [**read**, **understand** and **follow** this advice.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

Comment: i know you answered that question, but no change appear to me. please see this [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/watch/xe8b1vv26u46y49/8-16-2013_11-03-31_PM.mp4) 2)yes its related to the previous question 3)yes it is new question 4) why dont you allow me to contact you by Email... that would be really gratefull and gererous of you if you do that

Comment: 1.) No change appears, because both `100` and `500` iterations are more than enough. If this part of your problem has been answered, accept the answer and move on. If not, post a **clear** follow-up question. 2.) If your plot does not work, ask a new question. 3.) Post it 4.) This is a Q&A site. I prefer to answer questions here and/or post comments.

Comment: so how can i increase iteration number? i want to see the change in plot and minimum cost function...

Comment: it is better to say, how can i increase the value of iter (the variable which is created in the workspace)

Comment: Why do you want to increase that? What do you want to achieve? MATLAB only needs 14 iterations to converge ...

Comment: but for me just do 6 operation. i want to increase it to 14. because i optimized the kmean CostFunctoin with Imperialist Competitive Algorithm. and i see that the minimum CostFunction is less than what it appear with kmean. just this

Comment: @AliTahoori Now we are getting to the core. That should be a new question you ask. Explain that kmeans didn't find the minimum you can observe (explain how you found the minimum), that you tried to increase the iterations from kmeans but that the number of iterations isn't the issue. Then ask if kmeans is the correct approach or if something better should be tried. Again, that is a **new** question, not an edit to this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`statset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/statset.html) to change the number of iterations:

```
optns = statset('MaxIter',500);
```

And the call `kmeans` like this:

```
[idx,ctrs]=kmeans(cluster_data,3,'dist','city', ...   
                  'display','iter','replicate',100,'options',optns);
```

*Comment*
The documentation for [`kmeans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) states:

> MaxIter - Maximum number of iterations allowed. The default is 100.

So if you change the value of `MaxIter` it should be a number different from `100`.

Comment: no, please see my code which i add it to my post.

Comment: pls look carefully.! [link](http://www.rodfile.com/2fml1ar40tlg)

Comment: i have a bad condition here. i would be really gatefull if i have your email.

Comment: yes, there is rar file. it contain my data and code. just try to find "free download" buttom. it is obvious.

Comment: which upload center do u know that you can easily deal with it!...

Comment: my code is too long... it shows me error message.

Comment: no body is here!? i updated the post yesterday.

Comment: @AliTahoori What are you talking about? Have you not seen my comment to the question **after** you edited it?